# Which other color belongs in the group?

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern

Group 1: brown, white, green, gray, ___________

Group 2: all other colors

Exactly one other color belongs in group 1. Which color is it (i.e. fill in the blank), and why?

Comment: I think fourth one maybe black or blue

Comment: Is group 1 restricted to five elements?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, there are only five colors that belong in group 1. It's not restricted to five, but there is a reason that those five colors belong in a group to which no other colors belong. I will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: Is the [tag:sports] tag applicable here, by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Black*, because it's the only other [common color surname](https://linguistlist.org/ask-ling/message-details1.cfm?asklingid=200304670).

Comment: Poor [Jason Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Orange)

Comment: I think you're on the right lines with this but I also think the answer must be more specific than this - Gold is also fairly common in some circles... My own feeling is there will be a connection with players on a particular sports team or leaders of a particular country - something like that...

Comment: Okay, so the green checkmark now says this is the intended answer but I can't help feeling this idea had more satisfying untapped potential...

Comment: @Stiv I agree this is a poor answer (Gold, Silver, Blue, and others enjoy some currency). I posted it because I suspected it was the answer the asker had intended.

Comment: No criticism of the quality of your answer intended :) I'd been thinking along similar lines but had been sure there must be more to it than a subjective 'most common' solution (Where do you draw the cutoff line? Which country? Which data source?). I'm just a touch disappointed there wasn't more to it, that's all...!

Comment: ^ @GaryS. Not a great idea to post links that auto-download files to people's devices - would be best to provide a link to a website from which visitors could choose to start the download or not... Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv, you're right. Here's a link to a web page: http://bit.ly/2RZGW7K

Comment: Thanks @GaryS. Welcome to Puzzling, by the way! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the second and the fifth letters from the colours, you get 'bow', 'wit', 'gee', and 'gay', which are all valid words.

Therefore, according to this logic:

> **Violet** should fit the rule since applying the rule gives *volt*.

Comment: _Beige_ and _daisy_ and _blonde_ and _spice_ and _blood_ fit also, then, and doubtless more colors do, too.

Comment: You're right. It will be better to wait for a hint before posting an answer.

Comment: Great idea! Very clever. But as @msh210 rightly points out, this is not what I have in mind.